# Convergence of an integral of a function

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

[image]

Looking at the last line, we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} f(n)\leq f(1) +  \int_1^N  f  \leq f(1) +  \int_1^\infty f $$

I'm extremely disturbed by the fact the fact that the two integrals lies on the interval [1,N] and $$[1, \infty)$$, respectively. 
Why isn't it the case that 
$$f(1) + \int_2^N  f  \leq f(1) +  \int_2^\infty f$$

Comment: You can use \infty for infinity.

Comment: One reason is because when you do the proof step by step, as above, then it turns out to be $\int_1$ rather than $\int_2$. Another reason: if you actually draw the areas in the plane that these sums and integrals represent (where $f(n)$, in this case, is the area of a rectangle with height $f(n)$ and width $1$, whose base runs from $x=n-1$ to $x=n$), then you'll see where the specific endpoints come from.

Comment: I see that. Thank you (: